# Convert pandas series with list of dictonaries to dataframe with columns from dictonary

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I've a pandas series with list of dictonaries :

```
series = pd.Series(
    [[{'id': '1', 'val': 'ab'}, {'id': '2', 'val': 'abc'}], [{'id': '1', 'val': 'aa'}, {'id': '2', 'val': 'ewe'}],
     [{'id': '3', 'val': 'aea'}, {'id': '4', 'val': 'te'}]],
    index=['2014-01-01 22:59:00+00:00', '2014-01-02 22:59:00+00:00', '2014-01-03 21:59:00+00:00'])
```

```
2014-01-01 22:59:00+00:00    [{'id': '1', 'val': 'ab'}, {'id': '2', 'val': 'abc'}]
2014-01-02 22:59:00+00:00    [{'id': '1', 'val': 'aa'}, {'id': '2', 'val': 'ewe'}]
2014-01-03 22:59:00+00:00    [{'id': '3', 'val': 'aea'}, {'id': '4', 'val': 'te'}]
```

I would like to convert this to Dataframe with columns like :

```
                           id   val
2014-01-01 22:59:00+00:00   1   ab
2014-01-01 22:59:00+00:00   2   abc
2014-01-02 22:59:00+00:00   1   aa
......
```

Any idea on how to implement that ?
Thanks

I tried using pandas pd.dataframe method with different parameters.

```
df = pd.DataFrame(series)
```

Comment: Please give a reproducible data sample

Comment: here you go.

sample = pd.Series([
    [{'id': '1', 'val': 'ab'}, {'id': '2', 'val': 'abc'}], 
    [{'id': '1', 'val': 'aa'}, {'id': '2', 'val': 'ewe'}], 
    [{'id': '3', 'val': 'aea'}, {'id': '4', 'val': 'te'}]
    ],
    index=['2014-01-01 22:59:00+00:00', '2014-01-02 22:59:00+00:00', '2014-01-03 21:59:00+00:00']
    )

Answer (score 1):

Your sample is a Pandas Series and not a DataFrame. 
So create a dataframe with two columns, convert every column and rejoin the DataFrame.

```
df = pd.concat([sample.apply(pd.Series)[column].apply(pd.Series) for column in df.columns])
print(df.head())
```

Output:

```
                           id   val
2014-01-01 22:59:00+00:00   1   ab
2014-01-02 22:59:00+00:00   1   aa
2014-01-03 21:59:00+00:00   3   aea
2014-01-01 22:59:00+00:00   2   abc
2014-01-02 22:59:00+00:00   2   ewe
2014-01-03 21:59:00+00:00   4   te
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the method `explode()` (new in Pandas 0.25.0)  to expand your table vertically and the method `apply(pd.Series)` to expand you table horizontally:

```
series.explode().apply(pd.Series)
```

Output:

```
                          id  val
2014-01-01 22:59:00+00:00  1   ab
2014-01-01 22:59:00+00:00  2  abc
2014-01-02 22:59:00+00:00  1   aa
2014-01-02 22:59:00+00:00  2  ewe
2014-01-03 21:59:00+00:00  3  aea
2014-01-03 21:59:00+00:00  4   te
```